# unable to import chatterbot in python

Tags: python, chatterbot

python app.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatbot import chatbot
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\try_projects\chat_bot\chatbot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'
```

Code is

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer, ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
 

chatbot= ChatBot('Crazy')
```

what might be the solution to this problem?
python version: 3.8.3

Comment: Did you installed it ?

Comment: unable to install. spacy isn't being installed

Comment: So the problem is not `unable to import`, but `unable to install` ^^

Comment: ohhh yes! Can you help me out with installation?

Comment: just use pip to install a python package https://pypi.org/search/?q=chatbot

Comment: ok, but can you tell me why am i getting this error?  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/e2/46650d03c7ff2b57ed7af211d41c3f606540f7adea92b5af65fcf9f605c0/spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error

Comment: Can you paste the attempted install command you used into the question, along with the error output?

Comment: pip install chatterbot || error : 0/spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error

Answer (score 5):

Try installing the previous version of ChatterBot.

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.4
```

This should work, unless there are some other problems. I had the same problem and it worked for me.

There would be another problem if you are using Python 3.8.x  . In Python 3.8.x, a few functions of a few modules were removed.
You will be able to import ChattberBot , but when you name the bot, there will be an error.

```
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 264, in <module>
time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Copy the location for the file given in the last line, where the error occurs.

```
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py
```

Open file with IDLE or whatever editor you have. Please do Not open the file directly(this will run the file, and you will not be able to see the code) , instead Open with IDLE or Your Text editor
Then , go to line 264  in that . It would be written

```
time_func = time.clock
```

Instead of this change it to

```
time_func = time.perf_counter()
```

I Hope this helped! This was my first answer on StackOverflow !